# Where is MongoDB.Bson?

Tags: c#, mongodb, bson

The official guidelines to MongoDB using the C# driver point to their nuget package 'mongocsharpdriver'. However since newer releases, the namespace `MongoDB.Bson` doesn't seem to be included anymore. Where can I get this from?

Comment: The source definitely contains that namespace: https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver/tree/master/src/MongoDB.Bson

Comment: @clcto Yeah, already found it. Is there a reason they took that one out?

Comment: Did you figure this out? The namespace MongoDB.Bson comes from the assembly MongoDB.Bson which is included in the nuget package and should be referenced automatically.

Comment: @CraigWilson Yep, everything works now. I guess I've installed the package right when they separated it from the MongoDb assembly, but did not yet included it in the nuget or something. When I download the package now, MongoDb.Bson comes shipped with